# How I can allow only one IP by .htaccess in nginx admin?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Please, how I can allow only one ip by .htaccess in nginx admin ?

Like this in Apache.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

But this work in Apache only

I want command's works in nginx admin ..

So can the owner of IP,   Just browse the folder and files

Note: I use nginx admin on my servers http://www.nginxcp.com/installation-instruction/

help me for this please

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your nginx.conf:

```
server {
...
  allow 111.222.333.444;
  deny all;
...
}
```

PS: Nginx does not support .htaccess

If you want to limit specified directories:

```
server {
  ...
  location /users/111 {
    allow 111.222.333.444;
    deny all;
  }
  location /users/123 {
    allow 222.333.444.111;
    deny all;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: this in .htaccess ? , I added the code in .htaccess , But I can browse the files in the folder !!

Comment: @ALMGHARI No, this is your nginx.conf . Nginx does not support .htaccess

Comment: But I want the code in  .htaccess in folders site, To be a special folder for each user can access to it by IP

Comment: You can play with location. But anyway - config must be set in nginx.conf, not .htaccess.